# What are the ordering guarantees of AIDL "oneway" remote calls?

Tags: android, aidl, android-binder

AIDL methods and interfaces marked with the "**oneway**" keyword are asynchronous Binder calls for *remote* processes, and it is said that the ordering of the calls is not guaranteed. On the other hand, the last comment of Dianne Hackborn (author of Binder) in this thread (
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/FFY-hg2Jx0M) says:

> "ordering of delivery is tied to the target object (so you can receive calls on different 
>   interfaces out of order)"

Which seems to suggest, that calls to the same interface keep their order.

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 16):

As a general rule, oneway calls are asynchronous and can be dispatched on different threads concurrently with no ordering guarantees.  However, the system imposes special ordering guarantees on oneway calls happening on the same `IBinder` object: in this case the transactions will be dispatched one at a time, in order of the original calls.  Note that this ordering **only** applies in the specific case of oneway calls on the same `IBinder` object.  Anything else -- calls on different `IBinder` objects or mixing oneway and sync calls -- will not give you any ordering guarantees between them.

The way this work is that in the kernel each `IBinder` object has a queue of oneway transactions to dispatch.  A oneway call adds to that queue (a non-oneway call bypasses the queue).  Transactions are dispatched out of the queue one at a time, as each previous transaction completes.  So you may see these calls being dispatched on different threads, but the system makes sure that only one is executing at a time.  (Again only for a single `IBinder` object, oneway calls on two different `IBinder` objects can execute concurrently.)

Comment: Also worth noting that oneway calls made to an object local in your process operate as normal method calls and are _not_ async.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, all transactions in Binder are synchronous, meaning that a client initiates a call and waits a reply from a server. However, in case of oneway communication, the server received such call simply returns, thus, this type of communication is oneway.

The calls in a service are processed in different Binder threads, thus, in case of synchronous communication you can be sure that the client will receive the reply after the request (because the client waits for the response from the server). However, in case of oneway call it can be a case that your requests from the client will be processed in different Binder threads. That is why, to my point of view, it is written that the order are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

AIDL calls are synchronous by default which means the client will be in waiting state until method returns but in case we use "oneway" keyword,the method call is asynchronous i.e it returns immediately and client will receive callback later.Hence,the ordering is not defined for callbacks.