# Android IPC Binder - onTransact() waiting for previous one to return

Tags: android, ipc, android-binder

I have an application that is using IPC.

My main application is receiving **one-way** callbacks from a remote service.
Upon receiving those callbacks I'm doing some timely work (1-20s).
If I understand correctly - this work is done on a binder Thread on which the **onTransact()** method was called.

```
received on: Thread[Binder:12019_2,5,main]
```

Sometimes the callbacks are sent by the service faster then the work from the previous callback is done. (The remote service is also controlled by me so I know the exact timing).

The problem is I don't receive the callback in my main application immediately on a different binder Thread - the callback is **waiting** for the previous onTransact() to return and only then the main application receives the callback on the same Thread as the previous one.

so again:

```
received on: Thread[Binder:12019_2,5,main]
```

I think that my understanding of Binder stuff is insufficient.

From documentation:

> The system maintains a pool of transaction threads in each process
> that it runs in. These threads are used to dispatch all IPCs coming in
> from other processes. For example, when an IPC is made from process A
> to process B, the calling thread in A blocks in transact() as it sends
> the transaction to process B. The next available pool thread in B
> receives the incoming transaction, calls Binder.onTransact() on the
> target object, and replies with the result Parcel.

In my case process A (remote service) is calling transact() with `FLAG_ONEWAY` and process B (my app) should receive the incoming transaction on the 'next available pool thread'.

So why is it receiving it on the same as the one that is currently running?

Can I make the `onTransact()` **non-blocking**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the ordering guarantees of AIDL "oneway" remote calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565075/what-are-the-ordering-guarantees-of-aidl-oneway-remote-calls)